# Setting property of SVG elements from internal script

Tags: svg

It's possible to set the property of the elements of SVG direcly from the script?

For example

```
<svg width="100px" height="100px" version="1.1" onload="setValues()" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    function setValues() {

        //Set cx || cy || whatever of circle

        // Set property of rect

    }
    // ]]>
    </script>
    <circle id="circleId" cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="green" />
    <rect id="rectId" height="40" width="400" y="0" x="170" style="fill:#ffffff" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, setAttribute will do that.

```html
<svg width="100px" height="100px" version="1.1" onload="setValues()" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    function setValues() {

        // Set property of circle
        document.getElementById("circleId").setAttribute('cx', '20');
        // Set property of rect
        document.getElementById("rectId").setAttribute('x', '10');
        document.getElementById("rectId").setAttribute('style', 'fill:red');


    }
    // ]]>
    </script>
    <circle id="circleId" cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="green" />
    <rect id="rectId" height="40" width="400" y="0" x="170" style="fill:#ffffff" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, very quickly.
Is there some way to define a sort of constants for use in the elements?

Comment: you mean var x = 3; then call the function with x as the second argument? If you've other questions then probably best ask them separately or just read a book on javascript and the DOM (document object model).

Comment: No I mean using `<circle cx="myVarX" cy="myVarX" r="45" fill="green" />` I Know I changed littel bit my question, if necessary I'll open new question.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure I understand.
Your last aswer is for "you can't declare 'constants'" or "you don't need to open new question"?

Comment: You can't declare constants. You would need to ask another question if you want to further explore that.